# How to extract text from Excel Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**I have rows in Excel containing text similar to this:**

`[{"task":"Start","started":0},{"task":"security-oauth2-validate","started":27},{"task":"EncryptClientId.xsl","started":31},{"task":"set HTTP Header","started":70},{"task":"switch","started":74},{"task":"validate GetMemberRequest","started":77},{"task":"invoke MBEv2 REST Interface","started":94},{"task":"DashboardLogging.js","started":468},{"task":"set http header","started":508},{"task":"catch","started":513}]`

I would like to parse the text and find the difference between the start time of one task and the start time of the next task to find out how long each task takes.

**For example:**

- "invoke MBEv2 REST Interface" started at 94th ms
- "DashboardLogging.js" started at 468th ms .
- I would like to know the time taken by this task -> "invoke MBEv2 REST Interface"

Could someone please let me know how this can be achieved in Excel?

Comment: In Excel you can do `=468-94` and the cell will return `374`. Alternatively, if you want to parse the JSON (?) you can find some examples online.  What have you tried so far to extract those values?

Comment: it's not clear what you want to do. Do you need to parse the JSON? 
If you just want to use this as text and extract the values you mention you'll need to look into using FIND to get the position of the number you want and then RIGHT to grab the value. 
Not sure why you would do it like this, but then again, the question is not clear ;)

Comment: I would like to add some more description of the task :
Each task has its own start time . 
For Example  "invoke MBEv2 REST Interface" started at 94th ms .
For Example  "DashboardLogging.js" started at 468th ms .

I would like to know the time taken by this task ->  "invoke MBEv2 REST Interface"

Comment: If you only have start times for a task, how can you compute how long the task takes?  Don't you need an end time also?

Comment: Use a VBA library to parse the JSON, then loop over the resulting collection and subtract each time from the next.  I'm pretty sure even if you could use formulas for this it would not be fun.

Comment: You can `FIND` the string`"""started"":"` extract the number from `MID` string, and `SUBSTITUTE` things like `","` or `"}"` in case you overshoot - MSDN has articles on how to use all those functions.  If you have specific issues with the formula you try, we can help solve issues with a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to extract the numbers myself using the below formulas (assuming F2 column has the above JSON record):

Time when invoke started (column L):
=INT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(F2,SEARCH("invoke MBE",F2)+39,5),"}",""),"{",""),",",""))

Time when Dashboard Logging Started (column N)
=INT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(F2,SEARCH("Dashboard",F2)+31,5),"}",""),"{",""),",",""))

Time taken by Invoke
=N2-L2